# Armadillo C++: most efficient way to calculate using submatrix

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

Suppose I have two armadillo matrices A and B, and I want to calculate matrix product of two submatrices from both. I wonder what is the most efficient way to achieve it? Thanks

```
arma::mat A;
arma::mat B;

// suppose the dimensions work, I want to take product of two submatrices
arma::mat Asub = A.rows(1,2);
arma::mat Bsub = B.rows(3,4);

arma::mat result = Asub * Bsub;

// the calculation above needs copy and paste and looks to be inefficinet.
```

Efficient way to calculate product of two submatrices

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The site has established some rules and customs over the years, the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) may help you find your way around as .... this question is really not of the type preferred here.

Comment: sorry about it, may I know why the question is not preferred? Maybe the description is not clear? I got the problem when I use armadillo in Rcpp thus I also post it there.

Comment: No per the documentation at https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat (which you _surely_ consulted, right? ;-) ) these are _views_ meaning no copies are made.